# Why the query works in mysql, prepare statement is working, but bind_param isn't?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like:

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM foo WHERE id =' . $foo;
```

Here `$foo = 1`

This query executes in MySQL correctly and prepare statement with a query parameter returns an object for me (so I assume it's has been prepared successfully).

But when I'm trying to bind it (`$stmt->bind_param('i', $foo)`), it returns false for me. In other places (with almost exact query) my bind_param works perfectly.

Could someone tell me who can cause this problem?

My full code:

```
public function foo($foo)
{
    $query = 'DELETE FROM foo WHERE id =' . $foo; // I pass 1 here
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query); // returns an object
    var_dump($stmt->bind_param('i', $foo)); // returns false
}
```

Comment: Please add the full code where you use `bind_param()`.

Comment: Show __full__ code.

Comment: `$query = 'DELETE FROM foo WHERE id =' . $foo; ` that doesn't look like a bindable query

Comment: Post is edited. That's basically the whole function that I use at the moment.

Comment: The query need to look like this `DELETE FROM foo WHERE id = ?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change query like below:-

```
public function foo($foo)
{
    $query = 'DELETE FROM foo WHERE id =?'; //check the change here
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $foo); 
}
```

Reference:-

[mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

[PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: But then, why it does bind in other place without using `?` ?? In other place I was using a parameter as well.

Comment: @HELPME there may be you have some other code. Until i can see i can't comment

Comment: I basically just copied the code from other function and tried to bind it in my own function. But in the current function it doesn't work.